# Add incrememter to id in ejs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ejs, canjs, canjs-view

I am working on a javascript page that uses an MVC format and canJS. In my view property when I add new elements I want to add id's and dynamically assign new ids to each thing I load.

The code in my .ejs file is somehting like this:

```
<ul>
<% can.each(pages, function(val, key){ %>
<li id="<% 'page' + // Add incrementer here%>"><%= val.attr('Title') %>
</li>
</ul>
```

Where pages is iterable. I want to add an incrementer so every page I add has a unique id for reference later. Is this possible in the .ejs file?

Thanks

Comment: Is pages an array? Then, the "key" parameter should be the current element's index, which should be perfectly usable as an incrementer: http://canjs.com/docs/can.each.html

Comment: @HannesObweger great call. Post as an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the iterable provided to `can.each` is an array, the callback function of `can.each` receives the current element's index as its second parameter. This should be perfectly usable as an identifier.

See http://canjs.com/docs/can.each.html

Answer (score 3):

EJS is simply embedded javascript. You can use loop through the array pages using `forEach`, and the key variable would increment with every page (basically what Hannes Obweger suggested).

```
<ul>
    <% pages.forEach(function(val, key) { %>
        <li id="page_<%= key %>"><%= val.Title %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```